# The 'R2jags::autojags()' Function Doesn't Converge

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, r2jags

I'm running the following code:

```
Data_Frame <- structure(list(Predictor_Variable = c(20.5273283761926, 11.4039835403673, 5.31423215288669, 12.5192134582903, 15.8487716107629, 7.16369490255602, 3.91227747895755, 8.90797802712768, 14.1797202872112, 4.82832778943703, 14.3634092528373, 18.3354590029921, 1.56595673179254, 15.27424925589, 2.01471757609397, 17.8340036130976, 24.4356162613258, 24.7056286665611, 8.86376699781977, 3.95776731311344, 1.70528281596489, 24.1929906886071, 7.84694050671533, 2.11047385819256, 24.8220994370058, 14.8339046107139, 19.9926545028575, 19.0412578289397, 4.78973534191027, 18.7796145037282, 19.3868586677127, 14.6739382355008, 20.0653701729607, 19.6233123773709, 7.19542927108705, 16.7649424169213, 9.41006114007905, 19.2996966594364, 21.0871973482426, 13.0715743871406, 17.3938042367809, 18.3959823509213, 9.12836091592908, 2.27788038901053, 10.3573848318774, 4.74680115585215, 9.6620995842386, 16.9264123018365, 11.6498990275431, 20.4607627529185, 24.9407043796964, 21.8109163164627, 11.807474057423, 0.530748104210943, 9.57337225554511, 16.5205421217252, 2.07126556197181, 14.2894889519084, 5.47687077778392, 17.44882510975, 14.0162174822763, 11.7680913361255, 1.04056366835721, 1.95715780719183, 21.3338757341262, 19.7388443630189, 18.9714497013483, 19.5131896412931, 14.1728786868043, 10.4211826983374, 0.625250476878136, 17.7159008861054, 17.5371950492263, 3.91660461900756, 20.3449436288793, 1.5704334480688, 13.397057261318, 20.7767494546715, 7.27919469354674, 23.8504881446715, 19.7164187382441, 5.95191353349946, 20.7321806927212, 10.5640658119228, 16.616114001954, 15.9614237083588, 3.23146634036675, 16.6699483001139, 14.8473161039874, 18.7451402307488, 3.54583212174475, 5.97735904157162, 8.23308551334776, 3.3043225936126, 9.93713270290755, 5.86233736248687, 2.55345033365302, 11.350765300449, 7.88409785600379, 16.5159953408875), Response_Variable = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
sink("Generalised Logistic Function Model.txt")
cat("model {
    
    # Priors
    Intercept ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
    Slope ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
    Exponent ~ dlnorm(0, 1)
    Sigma ~ dlnorm(0, 1)
    Tau <- (1 / (Sigma ^ 2))
    
    # Likelihood and Model Fit
    for (i in 1:Number_of_Observations) {
      Response[i] ~ dnorm(Mean[i], Tau)
      Mean[i] <- ((1 + exp(-(Intercept + (Slope * Predictor[i])))) ^ (-Exponent))
      Actual_Squared_Residual[i] <- ((Response[i] - Mean[i]) ^ 2)
      Simulated_Response[i] ~ dbern(Mean[i])
      Simulated_Squared_Residual[i] <- ((Simulated_Response[i] - Mean[i]) ^ 2)
    }
    Bayesian_p_Value <- step((sum((Simulated_Squared_Residual[]) ^ 2)) / (sum((Actual_Squared_Residual[]) ^ 2)) - 1) 
    
  }", fill = T)
sink()
Parameters <- c("Intercept", "Slope", "Exponent", "Bayesian_p_Value")
Data <- list(Predictor = Data_Frame$Predictor_Variable, Response = Data_Frame$Response_Variable, Number_of_Observations = 100)
Initial_Values <- function () {
  list()
}
(Output_1 <- R2jags::jags(Data, Initial_Values, Parameters, "Generalised Logistic Function Model.txt", n.chains = 3, n.thin = 1, n.iter = 1000, n.burnin = 100, working.directory = getwd()))
```

When I run this Bayesian model, I get the following output:

```
Inference for Bugs model at "Generalised Logistic Function Model.txt", fit using jags,
 3 chains, each with 1000 iterations (first 100 discarded)
 n.sims = 2700 iterations saved
                 mu.vect sd.vect    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%  Rhat n.eff
Bayesian_p_Value   0.436   0.496   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000   1.000 1.003   870
Exponent           1.122   1.002   0.149   0.431   0.811   1.412   3.900 1.189    16
Intercept         -3.550   3.022 -11.786  -4.783  -2.785  -1.452   0.148 1.299    14
Slope              0.259   0.124   0.117   0.173   0.221   0.300   0.597 1.197    18
deviance         112.166   2.789 108.793 110.218 111.477 113.362 119.313 1.008   270

For each parameter, n.eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor (at convergence, Rhat=1).

DIC info (using the rule, pD = var(deviance)/2)
pD = 3.9 and DIC = 116.0
DIC is an estimate of expected predictive error (lower deviance is better).
```

Then when I try using the `R2jags::autojags()` function, I get the following output:

```
(Output_2 <- R2jags::autojags(Generalised_Logistic_Function_Model_Output, Rhat = 1.05))
Inference for Bugs model at "Generalised Logistic Function Model.txt", fit using jags,
 3 chains, each with 1000 iterations (first 0 discarded)
 n.sims = 3000 iterations saved
                 mu.vect sd.vect    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%  Rhat n.eff
Bayesian_p_Value   0.377   0.485   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000   1.000 1.020   110
Exponent           0.889   0.831   0.037   0.339   0.670   1.186   3.195 1.757     6
Intercept         -8.189  12.251 -47.264  -5.649  -3.372  -1.833  -0.135 1.831     6
Slope              0.473   0.560   0.126   0.191   0.241   0.350   2.130 1.871     6
deviance         112.520   2.919 108.919 110.427 111.930 113.896 119.283 1.103    28

For each parameter, n.eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor (at convergence, Rhat=1).

DIC info (using the rule, pD = var(deviance)/2)
pD = 4.0 and DIC = 116.5
DIC is an estimate of expected predictive error (lower deviance is better).
```

I was under the impression that this function would continue to run until it converges (until `Rhat` reached `1.1`). This isn't the case - the second model actually has higher `Rhat` values. I've tried playing around with the `Rhat` argument in the `autojags()` function but that hasn't helped. I can see that the second model didn't discard any of the initial iterations, but since it started with a model that was already decent (the model I got using the `jags()` function), it shouldn't matter. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the code for `autojags()` looks like.  We'll go through to see how it works:

1. update the object using the thinning and iterations you indicate in the function call.

```r
   n.burnin = object$n.iter
    n.thin.auto <- max(1, floor((n.iter - n.burnin)/1000))
    n.thin <- ifelse(n.thin > n.thin.auto, n.thin, n.thin.auto)
    if (any(!class(object) %in% c("rjags", "rjags.parallel"))) 
        stop("model must be a rjags object")
    object <- update(object, n.iter = n.iter, n.thin = n.thin, 
        refresh = refresh, progress.bar = progress.bar, ...)
```

2. Check to see if any R-hat values are bigger than the R-hat value specified in the function call.

```r
    check <- any(object$BUGSoutput$summary[, "Rhat"] > Rhat)
```

3. If the R-hat values are all smaller than the one in the function call, then stop, otherwise keep going.

```r
    if (check) {
```

4. Initialize a counter and while that counter is less than `n.update` (which defaults to 2) and while at least one of the R-hat values is bigger than the one indicated in the function call, do what is in the braces.

```r
        count <- 1
        while (check & (count < n.update)) {
```

5. Update the previously estimated model again, with the same iterations, thinning, etc...

```r
            object <- update(object, n.iter = n.iter, n.thin = n.thin, 
                refresh = refresh, progress.bar = progress.bar, 
                ...)
```

6. Increment the `count` counter and check convergence again.

```r
            count <- count + 1
            check <- any(object$BUGSoutput$summary[, "Rhat"] > 
                Rhat)
```

7. Continue through the loop until the condition is met and return the result

```r
        }
    }
    return(object)
```

In your call to `autojags()`, you're using the default `n.iter` (1000) and default `n.update` (2).  This means that the function will stop at a maximum of 3000 iterations (1000 for the first run through and 1000 additional for each of the 2 updates) regardless of convergence.  Bayesian models are only guaranteed to converge as the number of draws from the posterior approaches infinity.  The stopping rules are there so your computer won't try to run for infinite time.  It's also worth noting that the checking is not done iteration-by-iteration, but `n.iter`-by-`n.iter` chunks.